# Sort Knowledge Articles by custom logic rather than publish Date

Tags: knowledge, content, articles, setup, sortorder

Hoping someone can help me out here.
I am working on set up of public customer knowledge center but the articles need to be sorted in a specific logical manner and not in the order they were published.

I can publish initially in the order that I need them, however future updates to articles will alter the order. Is there any way that anyone has found to force a logical order of knowledge articles regardless of publish date?

Comment: Unless your 'custom logic' falls into a narrow area supported by out of the box list view, the answer is - write custom code. https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdpiRUAR/enable-sort-options-for-articles-in-communities